# How to custom format cells to check the difference between theme in excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have three columns

```
A|B|C
-----
4|3|2
4|4|5
4|5|6
5|3|2
5|4|4
5|5|6
5|6|8
```

I want to compare current column with previous and mark if it is less/equal/greater. I would like to use Icon condition formating so at the end the table should looks like this:

```
A|B|C
-----
4|<3|=3
4|=4|>5
4|>5|<2
5|<3|>5
5|<4|=4
5|=5|>6
5|>6|<2
```

Now I have to create separate rule for each cell :( there must be a better way?

Here is what i have now:

one formula for each cell
[image: one formating formula for each cell]
[image: formula details]

And now for column D I have to do the same :( New column will appear each week.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You should also explain how/why the values change in column C between your two tables.  Furthermore, be aware that you cannot use relative references with Icon formatting, and combine the Icon and the value in the same cell.  You could use the symbology you show using the regular number formatting rules.  You should be able to do what you describe with three rules.

Answer (score 0):

If just for 16 rows a CF rule for each seems viable but for a much larger number of rows an approach as mentioned by [@Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) in a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332295/how-to-custom-format-cells-to-check-the-difference-between-theme-in-excel#comment66003663_39332295) may be less work, if not a result identical to icon sets:

The rules:

[image: CF formula rules]

The bottom rule is:

```
=AND(B1=D1,COUNT(B1:D1)>1)
```

The outcome:

[image: Example outcome]

There is a formula in C2 (a newly inserted column) of:

```
 =IF(B2=D2,"▬",(IF(B2>D2,"▲",(IF(B2<D2,"▼","")))))
```

copied down to suit, and grid lines are not displayed but borders added all round, except to the right of ColumnC, instead. For subsequent weeks ColumnC may be inserted 'over' ColumnG etc.